# turning transition, with !important value, off on responsive

Tags: css, media-queries

So I got this code for a section in my page that uses a "!important" value on the css to make it work properly but I feel like it might be affecting the responsive side of it. I currently got the section to look properly on small devices but once I click(or hover) anywhere on the section, the section once again goes weird and I can't help but to think that the `.projects-others:hover {width: 60% !important;}` is behind it since it won't let me turn the transition off. How can I take it off for small devices but keep it on regular size? I've even tried putting the !important value on the transition queries but still no luck.

```css
/*project section starts*/

.projects {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 27em;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: ;
}

.projects a {
  cursor: default;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 1.1px 1.2px #595959;
}

.projects h1 {
  font-size: 4.40em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.projects-others,
.projects-coding {
  width: 50%;
  -moz-transition: width .3s;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s;
  -o-transition: width .3s;
  transition: width .3s;
  height: 27em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.projects-others {
  float: right;
  background: #00004d;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.projects-coding {
  background: white;
  border-right: ;
}

.projects:hover .projects-others {
  width: 40%;
}

.projects-coding:hover {
  width: 60%;
}
/*the code that I think is causing the problem*/
.projects-others:hover {
  width: 60% !important;
}

.projects-others:hover~.projects-coding {
  width: 40%;
}


/*courosel section starts*/

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 7.5em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 7.5px auto;
}

.mySlides,
.mySlides2 {
  display: none;
}

.project-text {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
}

.slideshow-img {
  width: 17.4rem;
  height: 10.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: display 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.slide-hover-p {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow-img:hover+.slide-hover-p {
  display: block;
}

.fade-car {
  -moz-animation-name: fade-car;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-car;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

.previous,
.nexxt {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: ;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition: 0.85s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.nexxt {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.previous:hover,
.nexxt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#p-others:hover,
#n-others:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #00004d;
}

#p-coding:hover,
#n-coding:hover {
  background-color: #00004d;
  color: white;
}


/*courosel media queries*/

@-webkit-keyframes fade-car {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade-car {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .previous,
  .nexxt,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}

#coding-github-btn {
  font-size: 1.35em;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #00004d;
  border: 1px solid #00004d;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#coding-github-btn:hover,
#coding-github-btn:focus {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #00004d;
  color: #00004d;
}

#others-etsy-btn {
  font-size: 1.175em;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #ffdb4d;
  border: 1px solid #ffdb4d;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  color: #00004d;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#others-etsy-btn:hover,
#others-etsy-btn:focus {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/*media queries for section*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .projects {
  height: auto;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
 }
 .projects a {
  transition: none;
 }
 .projects-others, .projects-coding {
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans|Inknut+Antiqua|Dancing+Script|Courgette&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile-css/profile-stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile-css/mq-stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!--project section headings-->
<div class="projects">
  <a>
    <div class="box projects-others" style="color: #ffdb4d;">
      <h1 style="color: #ffdb4d;">Projects :<br> Others</h1>
      <!--slider starts-->
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade-car">
          <div class="project-text">
            <img src="images/colorado_view2.jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
            <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade-car">
          <div class="project-text">
            <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
            <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade-car">
          <div class="project-text">
            <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
            <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a id="p-others" class="previous" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a id="n-others" class="nexxt" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      </div>
      <!--slideshow ends-->
      <br><br>
      <div class="w-100 text-center">
        <a id="others-etsy-btn" href="#" class="btn" role="button">My Etsy Store <span class="fa fa-etsy"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div class="box projects-coding" style="color:#00004d;">
      <h1 style="color:#00004d;">Projects :<br> Coding</h1>
      <!--second slider starts-->
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides2 fade-car">
          <div class="project-text">
            <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
            <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides2 fade-car">
          <div class="project-text">
            <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
            <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides2 fade-car">
          <div class="project-text">
            <img src="images/global (35).jpg" class="slideshow-img img-fluid" alt="global6" />
            <p class="slide-hover-p"><i>(My Profile Webpage)</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a id="p-coding" class="previous" onclick="plusSlides2(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a id="n-coding" class="nexxt" onclick="plusSlides2(1)">&#10095;</a>
        <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot2" onclick="currentSlide2(3)"></span>
      </div>
      <!--slider ends-->
      <br><br>
      <div class="w-100 text-center">
        <a id="coding-github-btn" href="#" class="btn" role="button">My Repositories <span class="fa fa-github"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Latest compiled bootstrap JavaScript -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing a media query at the bottom of your css file with the same class and using important as well would definitely fix this.